# How to set src of img tag with variable in haml?

Tags: image, variables, haml

I would like to set src of img tag with variable.
I tested this variable and checked it in real url.
This is what I have done

```
%img{border: "0", height: "95", :src => "#{data[:photo]}", width: "250"}/
```

But it doesn't work still now.
I am not sure what the problem is.
Looking forward your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

data[:photo] didn't contain http or https
I added this and it work well.
Thanks.